# How to display image src before href in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have this block:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("img[src$='.jpeg'], img[src$='.jpg'], img[src$='.png'], img[src$='.gif']").wrap('<div class="b-img"/>').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', src).addClass('img-link').colorbox();    
        $(this).wrap(a);
        });
})(jQuery);
```

and after that have link like `<a href=""></a><img src>...` but I need `<img src>` before `<a href="">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead of `wrap`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("img[src$='.jpeg'], img[src$='.jpg'], img[src$='.png'], img[src$='.gif']").wrap('<div class="b-img"/>').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', src).addClass('img-link').colorbox();    
        $(this).after(a);
        });
})(jQuery);
```

*Edit based on comments by OP, for changing image src*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("img[src$='.jpeg'], img[src$='.jpg'], img[src$='.png'], img[src$='.gif']").wrap('<div class="b-img"/>').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', src).addClass('img-link').colorbox();    
        $(this).after(a);
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.yoursite.com/images/img1.jpg');
        });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

[insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) inserts the elements before `this`, like so:

```
$(function() {
   $("img").wrap('<div class="b-img"/>').each(function() {
     $('<a />', {href: this.src, 'class': 'img-link'}).colorbox().insertBefore(this);    
   });​
});​
```

Also, there should be no need to check for all available image file extensions, if you have images that are svg etc, use a class instead.